# How to Develop React App on Apache Webserver

Tags: reactjs, apache

i have got a problem, which i am trying to find a solution for weeks now.
I think it´s an understanding error on my side, but i couldn't figure it out.
What i am trying to do:

**Develop, not deploy, a react app on an Apache2 server.**

I know that react is an frontend library, so it should be possible to do.
I also know that nodeJs is kinda required to "npm" all the packages and to create the "Simple" react app..

What i want also to do:

1. Use the MATERIAL-UI
2. Build a PHP Backend
3. Collaborate with my Team Members (they should also work on the react app)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, your goal is that your development instance runs on Apache instead of Node while you're actively developing against it, correct?  Regarding #3 - I think you would be better off having everyone develop on their own instances and using a source control system like git with some kind of separation strategy (like development and master branches). Then the master branch where everyone's work is merged is deployed to the Apache server.

Comment: This is way too broad a question to be on topic IMHO (check [help/on-topic] and [ask])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting a ReactJS App is no different than hosting any other javascript code on any type of server - by having it as a static file on your web server and including it in the html returned from the server.

Depending on the way your React project is set up, you would:

- use node to build a javascript bundle of your react app (possibly by running "npm run build" in any CLI),
- include the resulting script file or files in the head element of your root or master template
- Make the Apache web server return the needed page with the master template where the script tag is

Additional setup could include starting the PHP server and react development build at the same time, but that is highly specific on your setup and would require you to add some more information on used frameworks and setup.

Comment: Then I would suggest that during development you start the Apache/PHP server separately, and start the node development server separately and talk to the PHP server over an API. There is no way to run the react build process in anything other than node, at least not in a safe way. An improvement might be that you create a batch file that starts both at the same time, to make it easier for Developers.

Comment: I want to develop on a server. I just want to develop the react app on a server. If it runs on a nodejs server or is "build" by PHP, doesn't matter to me. I just search for the simplest solution to do it.

Comment: The "Server" during development is your local PC running a node process. By running npm run dev, you are starting a local node server which automatically builds a development version of the react code and shows the result on a URL - usually localhost:3000. That is a pretty standard way of doing things.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to deploy apps with Apache and React.  The nodejs based- Webpack server is incompatible with Apache web server.  You'll have to pick one server or another, you can not route index.html -> index.tsx and vice versa.  Besides if you ever got both servers working in tandem with SSL, it's a technically security nightmare and has no production value.  It's best to avoid java(script) all together as it's merit in real software development has greatly diminished.  Mostly for gold diggers.